# Receiving notification in flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Whenever I receive a notification in firebase flutter, the notification is sent, and appears at the status bar, but my onbackgroundmessage handler isn't called or any onMessage functions. Any help is greatly appreciated. I will provide any further information that is necessary.

**main.dart**

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
```

Comment: When application is on foreground, what is happening? Can you get logs?

Comment: @AhmetKAYGISIZ in the foreground it is working.

Comment: onMessage: {notification: {title: a test message, body: a test message}, data: {}}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your code, but try this way, which is the way in the FlutterFire docs:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
 //...
});
```

But remember also that this code not enough to run when the app terminated where you need further work to handle Android and iOS to receive them.
FlutterFire really helps, also the example there: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview
Ready to help if it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't seem to work either. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the notifications working. What I did was send the notification with only data and no notification.
e.g.
BEFORE:

```
{notification: {title: 'my title', body: 'my body'}, data: {'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'}
```

NEW:

```
{data: {'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', 'title': 'my title', 'body': 'my body'}}
```